# Compile time Type declaration without using dynamic in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamic

I have 2 Models like Below,

```
public class AClass
{
    public int prop { get; set; }
    public virtual List<BClass> bClass { get; set; }
}

public class BClass
{
    public int prop1 { get; set; }
    public int prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Used these models in linq query

```
var data = testList.GroupBy(e => e.TestProp1).Select(g=> new AClass
{
    prop = g.Key,
    bClass = g.GroupBy(p=> p.TestProp2).Select(g1 => new BClass {
        prop1 = g1.FirstOrDefault().TestProp1,
        prop2 = g1.FirstOrDefault().TestProp2
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Now, there is a requirement to add a new property `prop3` in `BClass` without affecting to original `BClass`. So, I created inherited `CClass` and used it in linq,

```
public class CClass : BClass
{
    public int prop3 { get; set; }
}

var data1 = testList.GroupBy(e => e.TestProp1).Select(g=> new AClass
{
    prop = g.Key,
    bClass = g.GroupBy(p=> p.TestProp2).Select(g1 => new CClass {
        prop1 = g1.FirstOrDefault().TestProp1,
        prop2 = g1.FirstOrDefault().TestProp2
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

In this scenario, `bClass = g.GroupBy(p => p.TestProp2, (key1, g1) => new CClass` line giving error,
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestApp.CClass>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestApp.BClass>'`

*** Solution I Tried: ***

I Replaced following line from `AClass`

```
public virtual List<BClass> bClass { get; set; }`
```

with

```
public virtual dynamic bClass { get; set; }
```

it worked.

But, just for curiosity, without declaring it as dynamic property, How can I achieve it?

Comment: You would either have to cast your entire `List<BClass>` to a `List<CClass>` with the `.Cast<>()` method, or declare your Property on the `AClass` as `List<CClass>`. But why aren't you allowed to change BClass? Is this a task you were given from some form of class you're attending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `dynamic` at all. You just need to tell the compiler that you want a `BClass` from the second call to `Select`:

```
var data1 = testList.GroupBy(e => e.TestProp1).Select(g=> new AClass
{
    prop = g.Key,
    // this line here! Note the cast
    bClass = g.GroupBy(p=> p.TestProp2).Select(g1 => (BClass)(new CClass {
        prop1 = g1.FirstOrDefault().TestProp1,
        prop2 = g1.FirstOrDefault().TestProp2,
        prop3 = ... // why don't you also set prop3?

    })).ToList()
}).ToList();
```